# Function passed as parameter is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, websocket

I have `WsConnector` that is connecting to my backend application and is subscribing to WebSocket topic.

```
export class WsConnector {
    private stompClient: any;

    connect(onMessage: (msg) => void) {
        this.stompClient = Stomp.over(new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/ws'));
        this.stompClient.connect({}, () => {
            this.stompClient.subscribe('/topic/event', (msg: any) => {
                console.log('Msg received in WsConnector')
                onMessage(msg)
            });
        }, (err: any) => console.error(err));
    }
}
```

And I have another class that is using this class like this

```
export class SimpleClass {
    private ws = new WsConnector()

    private onMessageReceived(msg: any): void {
        console.log('Msg recevied in component')
    } 

    constructor() {
        this.ws.connect(() => this.onMessageReceived.bind(this))
    }
}
```

I'm sure that messages are received because I can see plenty of `Msg received in WsConnector` messages, but what I can't see is `Msg recevied in component` - messages are not passed to this function. Why is that?

Comment: Because the callback you're passing doesn't make sense. It doesn't accept any parameters (i.e. ignores the msg) and returns (but does not call) a bound method. Given that this is Angular, which already used RxJS, why not expose an *observable* and use the DI system rather than newing up an instance?

Comment: I found bug in my code, it's working now. However could you elaborate on that more, what do you mean by `why not expose an observable?`

Comment: I mean rather than making the consumer pass a callback, have an observable prop it can subscribe to. Like the stompClient does.

Answer (score 2):

Stupid mistake.

```
this.ws.connect(() => this.onMessageReceived.bind(this))
```

should be changed to

```
this.ws.connect(this.onMessageReceived.bind(this))
```